# Strip or Change User-Agent while using Header() Function to Redirect

Tags: php, user-agent

Is it possible to alter the User-Agent string before redirecting to a location in PHP with `header('Location: https://example.com/')`?

Comment: `User-Agent` header is sent by browser when sending any request , why would you want to alter it?

Comment: @Viney I specific use for it. It's the only way I can send some extra data